I have a doubt in inference using variable elimination in Bayesian network

how to calculate number of operations in this question

we can’t tell you until you give us the definition of each random variabile

I added the network can you explain the process

@Curious_knight welcome to AI Stack Exchange! If possible, please discuss the difficulties you are having with this problem or the steps you have taken when trying to find a solution. Thank you for posting, and we hope to see more of your questions here soon!
